# Individual instances works but array shows memory corruption

Tags: c++, arrays, ubuntu, boost, shared-ptr

I am facing a weird problem, which is related to arrays in C++. Basically, I made two instances of a class, and later I used these instances, which caused memory corruption error. The code works if I make individual two instances of this class without using array at all.

Please see the code snippet below-

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "my_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh("~");

    // this doesn't work
    PointCloudSubscriber pcs[2];
    pcs[0] = PointCloudSubscriber(nh, "/kinect1/sd/points", 1);
    pcs[1] = PointCloudSubscriber(nh, "/kinect2/sd/points", 1);

    // this works
    //PointCloudSubscriber pc1(nh, "/kinect1/sd/points", 1);
    //PointCloudSubscriber pc2(nh, "/kinect2/sd/points", 1);

    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        // this doesn't work
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
          ROS_INFO_STREAM("Cloud topic=" << pcs[i].topic << 
                          ", size=" << pcs[i].point_cloud.data.size());

        // this works
        //ROS_INFO_STREAM("Cloud topic=" << pc1.topic << 
        //                ", size=" << pc1.point_cloud.data.size());
        //ROS_INFO_STREAM("Cloud topic=" << pc2.topic << 
        //                ", size=" << pc2.point_cloud.data.size());

        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }

    return 0;
}

class PointCloudSubscriber
{
private:
    ros::Subscriber subscriber;
    void callback(
        const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& msg);

public:
    std::string topic;
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 point_cloud;
    PointCloudSubscriber(){};
    PointCloudSubscriber(
        ros::NodeHandle& node_handle,
        std::string topic_name,
        int queue_size);
};

void PointCloudSubscriber::callback(
    const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& msg)
{
    point_cloud = *msg;
}

PointCloudSubscriber::PointCloudSubscriber(
    ros::NodeHandle& node_handle,
    std::string topic_name,
    int queue_size)
{
    topic = topic_name;
    subscriber = node_handle.subscribe<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>(
        topic_name, queue_size, &PointCloudSubscriber::callback, this);
}
```

Below is the output reported-

```
[ INFO] [1526440334.856181149]: Cloud topic=/kinect1/sd/points, size=0
[ INFO] [1526440334.856210465]: Cloud topic=/kinect2/sd/points, size=0
*** Error in `/home/ravi/ros_ws/devel/lib/my_pcl_tutorial/check': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000000000128f220 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The interesting thing to note here is that each element of the array is able to get the correct `topic` but somehow fails to get the `point_cloud` attribute which is assigned from `boost::shared_ptr`.

Why such strange behavior? Is it an illegal use case of accessing `boost::shared_ptr`? Any suggestions, please?

*PS: I am using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit PC.*

Comment: What is `PointCloudSubscriber`? Does it follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `PointCloudSubscriber` is a custom class. The code of this class is already in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: A suspicious part is that the `subscribe` call has a `this` parameter. But when you copy or assign the subscriber, the copy will have a different `this`. That might violate the "rules of three, five or zero" others talk about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PointCloudSubscriber` is probably broken<sup>1</sup>. Instead of creating two default instances (1)<sup>2</sup> of `PointCloudSubscriber` and then assign them the "real" values (2)<sup>2</sup>, do:

```
PointCloudSubscriber pcs[2] = {
    PointCloudSubscriber(nh, "/kinect1/sd/points", 1),
    PointCloudSubscriber(nh, "/kinect2/sd/points", 1)
};
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> It looks like it handles resources, but only defines a user-provided constructor. You should observe [the rule of 0/3/5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

<sup>2)</sup> FYI, (1) and (2):

```
PointCloudSubscriber pcs[2]; // (1)
pcs[0] = PointCloudSubscriber(nh, "/kinect1/sd/points", 1); // (2)
pcs[1] = PointCloudSubscriber(nh, "/kinect2/sd/points", 1); // (2)
```

Comment: I don't have the access to the code now. However I tired a similar approach as well, i.e.,  `PointCloudSubscriber pcs[] = { pc1, pc2, pc3 };`  Please see [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/291029/fast-access-to-multiple-point-clouds/). Apologies for pointing to an external website.

Comment: @RaviJoshi not the same. here (--^) you still copy-initialize your broken class. Please, see the rule of 0/3/5.